# Deploying ember.js app to Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, ember.js

I have been trying to deploy my ember.js app to Heroku.  I got the following error message:

```
unknownc8e0eb148153:coffeeklatsch christopherspears$ heroku apps:create chriscoffeeklatsch
Creating chriscoffeeklatsch... done, stack is cedar
http://chriscoffeeklatsch.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:chriscoffeeklatsch.git
Git remote heroku added
unknownc8e0eb148153:coffeeklatsch christopherspears$ git push heroku master
Identity added: /Users/christopherspears/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/christopherspears/.ssh/id_rsa)
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 61, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (61/61), done.
Writing objects: 100% (61/61), 452.51 KiB | 149.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 61 (delta 23), reused 0 (delta 0)


 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

Auto packing the repository for optimum performance.
To git@heroku.com:chriscoffeeklatsch.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:chriscoffeeklatsch.git'
```

I wonder if the problem is I am just trying to deploy a straight up single page ember.js app. Seems like most ember apps deployed to Heroku are built with either rails or django.  Basically, my app just consists of an index.html file and an app.js and then some libraries and css files.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is a static website, then it has nothing to do on Heroku. Heroku is meant to run apps.

Instead, use [Amazon S3 Static Website Hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) (+ CloudFront, if you have the money) to host your website.

It'll be cheaper and faster anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is expecting a dynamic app, but don't worry, since it's easy to add something simple that will just server your static files.

Have a look at [How to deploy a static page the easy way](http://www.lemiffe.com/how-to-deploy-a-static-page-to-heroku-the-easy-way/)

Essentially all you need is to make it look like a php app (easier than Rails/DJango for what you need).

> Create an index.php file with the following code:

```
<?php include_once("yourstaticpage.html"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If youre using ember-cli there is a build pack that works great:

http://www.ember-cli.com/#deployments

Otherwise you can use a static site build pack:

https://github.com/abhishekmunie/heroku-buildpack-static/blob/master/README.md

Thats one of many you can find by searching google. Lastly, you can create your own build pack:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks